# cobbler_web unavailable on CentOS 7.6

Tags: centos7, apache2, cobbler

When I try to load the cobbler 2.8.4 web page I see the below error in /var/log/httpd/ssl_error_log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/cobbler/web/cobbler.wsgi", line 26, in application
_application = get_wsgi_application()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
django.setup(set_prefix=False)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/usr/share/cobbler/web/settings.py", line 89, in <module>
from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
ImportError: cannot import name TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
```

python2-django-1.11.20-1.el7.noarch 
cobbler-2.8.4-4.el7.x86_64 
cobbler-web-2.8.4-4.el7.noarch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Django has been updated in EPEL to 1.11, which made some changes in how [context processors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43251397/1068283) are handled. The code cobbler is trying to call here was deprecated and removed from Django some time ago, so cobbler needs to be updated. File a bug report against cobbler in Red Hat Bugzilla.